# Attempting to copy specific columns from one sheet and paste on new sheet side by side

Tags: excel, vba

I've been struggling with this for a while now, but I am trying to use VBA to copy 2 specific columns from multiple sheets and then paste them into a new sheet. I will attach a copy of the code I've been using. However, it will paste each copied column under the previous column instead of pasting the columns side by side.

```
Sub test1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_a As Worksheet
Dim ws_b As Worksheet
Dim HeaderRow_A As Long
Dim HeaderLastColumn_A As Long
Dim TableColStart_A As Long
Dim Q As Object
Dim SourceDataStart As Long
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim Source As Variant
Dim k As Long
Dim ws_B_lastCol As Long
Dim NextEntryline As Long
Dim SourceCol_A As Long
Dim P As Long
Dim m As Long

Set Q = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set ws_b = Worksheets(2)

m = 3
Set ws_a = Worksheets(m)

For Each ws In Worksheets

With ws_a
    SourceDataStart = 2
    HeaderRow_A = 2
    TableColStart_A = 1
    HeaderLastColumn_A = .Cells(HeaderRow_A, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For k = TableColStart_A To HeaderLastColumn_A
        If Not Q.Exists((.Cells(HeaderRow_A, k).Value)) Then
             Q.Add (.Cells(HeaderRow_A, k).Value), k
        End If
    Next k
End With

With ws_b
    ws_B_lastCol = .Cells(HeaderRow_A, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For k = 1 To ws_B_lastCol
        SourceCol_A = Q((.Cells(2, k).Value))

        If SourceCol_A <> 0 Then
            SourceLastRow = ws_a.Cells(Rows.Count, SourceCol_A).End(xlUp).Row
            Set Source = ws_a.Range(ws_a.Cells(SourceDataStart, SourceCol_A), ws_a.Cells(SourceLastRow, SourceCol_A))
            NextEntryline = .Cells(Rows.Count, k).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range(.Cells(NextEntryline, k), _
                   .Cells(NextEntryline, k)) _
                   .Resize(Source.Rows.Count, Source.columns.Count).Cells.Value = Source.Cells.Value
        End If

    Next k
End With


m = m + 1

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a loop `For Each ws In Worksheets` but `ws` is not used in that loop. What is the loop doing ? If `ws_a` never changes, why run the `With ws_a` loop multiple times ?

Comment: CDP1802 ws_a changes after each loop. i have it set at worksheets(m) which gets 1 added to it after each loop. An example would be ws_a = worksheets(3) runs the loop and then at the beginning of the next loop ws_a = worksheeets(4) and so on and so forth

Comment: `Set ws_a = Worksheets(m)` is outside the loop when m=3. Changing m doesn't automatically change ws_a.